# Rendering combined 2D and 3D maps in R

Tags: r, 3d, data-visualization, rgl

I saw this figure in Leland Wilkinson's book the Grammar of Graphics and was wondering how I could go about creating something similar in R.

[image: data visualization showing on the XY plane a color-filled map with contour lines for the US and floating above it in 3D a surface plot that corresponds to the contour lines shown in the XY plane]

I am suspicious this could be done using `rgl`, `persp3d`, but there's a couple aspects that are unclear to me like how to create the conformal mapping shown in the coordinates of the XY plane, as well as how to create the 2D color map in a 3D context.

Any advice would be much appreciated.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

That should be possible with `rgl`, but there might be some snags in the details.  Here's the outline:

1. The green surface does not appear to have a rectangular base,
   so you'll pass matrices for all of `x`, `y` and `z` coordinates to `surface3d()` to draw it.
2. I can't tell if the map is on a flat surface with curved edges, or if it's a curved surface.  In either case, you plot the surface with a 2D texture showing the map and the contours.

   a.  To produce that 2D texture, use whatever mapping software you've got, and output the image to a PNG file.

   b.  To put it on the surface, use `surface3d()` with arguments `texture = <filename>, texture_s = ..., texture_t = ...)` where `texture_s` and `texture_t` are set to coordinates in the image (bottom left = (0,0), top right = (1,1)) corresponding to each `x` and `y` location.  The `z` value is
   either constant or varying depending on whether you want it flat
   or curved.
3. The axes will be drawn with `axis3d`.